# Как узнать количество аргументов, передающихся функции?

Tags: python

Например, у меня есть код

```
def one(x, y = 0, z = 0):
   two(x, y, z)
def two(x, y):
    print x, y
```

Мне надо узнать количество аргументов, которое можно передать функции two без ошибки?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться модулем [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html)

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def foo(a, b=0, c=0):
...     pass
... 
>>> inspect.getargspec(foo)
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(0, 0))
```

Comment: `getargspec()` устарела в Питоне 3. Можно использовать `inspect.getfullargspec()`, `inspect.signature()`. Лучше конечно документацию почитать или `help(two)` в REPL.

Answer (score 4):

или так

```
func.func_code.co_argcount
```

или так

```
func.__code___.co_argcount
```

Answer (score 2):

Так же можно применять конструкции типа `def a(*args,**kwargs):` в таком случае любое количество аргументов будет правильным